# Can you make toggleClass animation without jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fade, uiswitch, toggleclass

Can I make this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/default.html without jQuery UI?

Basically I have a simple site which the body has a class named: `'.bgone'`.

`.bgone` has **background color: #ccc** and I want to toggle the `.bgtwo` of which **backgroundcolor is #999** with the *fade effect*.

Is it possible with only jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how this would show background colors, but have you tried using jQuery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, to fade between background colors, you need JQuery UI or something similar. You might try this [color animation plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color), or alternatively, use CSS3 transitions and simply use jQuery to toggle animated classes.

Here is an example of CSS3 color animation with a JavaScript/JQuery trigger: http://jsfiddle.net/6nRj2/

Answer (score 1):

You can not animate colors with jQuery alone. You might need some plugins - it's still a separate file (and maybe a separate HTTP request), but significantly smaller then the UI.

Some of those

> - [Color animation jQuery-plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)
> - [jQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)